# Auto failover multiple connections to mirror database when principal goes down

Tags: c++, connection-string, connection-pooling, failover, database-mirroring

I have a principal database (server_A), mirror database (server_B), and a witness database (server_C). The databases are set up for automatic failover, that is, when server_A goes down or fails over, server_B assumes the role of the new principal database. The database quorum is set up correctly to the best of my knowledge.

I have written an application in c++ to connect to the database and get a value to ensure a true connection. The application detects when a failure occurs on the GetValue call and attempts to reconnect when the error occurs.

The issue is this:
When I have MULTIPLE connections to the database (two threads connected, once connected, it will get a value in a loop), when the failover occurs (stopping sql server on server A so server B will take over as principal), I detect the connection failure and destroy my connection and attempt to reconnect using the same connection string:

"Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=tcp:Server_A;Failover_Partner=tcp:Server_B;Database=SomeDatabase;Uid=SomeUser;Pwd=SomePassword;"

** NOTE **
I have verified that the failover has taken place by monitoring the databases.

Even though, the connection to the database has been properly disposed of, I cannot reconnect to the database until I restart the application, OR if I bring server_A back online (now acting as the mirror database) and then failover server_B (shutting down sql server) making server A the principal database again, the application can reconnect without having to completely close out.

Though I could manipulate the connection string to make server_B the new principal and server_A the new Failover_Partner, this is not an ideal solution as many more connections will be utilized.

Keep in mind, this ONLY happens with multiple connections to the database. If I run the application with only one connection, all is fine and I can reconnect just fine when the failover occurs.

**EDIT:** If I connect in the beginning with multiple threads, all is fine. When I shutdown SQL Server, and therefore a failover occurs, I can reconnect only when I go through and delete ALL objects and re-instantiate new objects. Also, I am using SQL Native Client 11.0 (ODBC). Thoughts?

Comment: It may very well be that the driver you are using is not thread safe, and when non-thread-safe lib is used in threaded environment results cannot be foreseen.

Comment: If this were the case, would the application not fail from the beginning without going through the mirror process? If it werent thread safe, I would suspect a failure would occur upon connecting multiple times regardless of a failover.

Comment: It may, it may not. It's really hard to predict what will happen when non-thread-safe code is exposed to threaded environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer.

I had to modify the hosts file because my application did not reside in the same domain as the databases. Therefore when trying to fail over, I could not reach the database with the instance name (which is what the failover partner was cached as). I changed the hosts file to resolve the instance name to the ip address of the machine and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you're describing is consistent with the issue described in [KB 2605597](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2605597) "Time-out error when a mirrored database connection is created by the .NET Framework data provider for SQLClient."

The KB describes problems when the connection timeout is set to 15 seconds, I have anecdotally heard of similar problems when the connection timeout is set to 0 (which isn't a good idea for other reasons, mentioning just in case).

This hotfix is applied to the application servers. If you want to rule this out as a possible cause, you could test raising the timeout (like it says in the workaround sections of the post) to make sure it's not the issue.

Later thought: The other thing I notice that is unusual is that you're specifying the TCP protocol in the connection string and the failover partner name. It's not clear to me from the documentation that it's supported in the failover partner name. You might want to try removing that and specifying the network attribute instead. ([Recommended here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366348(v=sql.105).aspx).)

I do understand that you believe the issue isn't these things due to the single / multiple connections issue you've tested out.

However, I think you're better off simplifying the connection string so it's as consistent as possible with the published examples and making sure it's not the issues that people have commonly hit with this first. (The retry issue happens when there is latency, which can make it somewhat sporadic.)

Comment: The connection string provided has been modified in multiple ways in hopes that it was the issue. I have tried messing with the Network parameter, but still received the same result. I am not certain of the tcp: tag on the failover partner either, I couldnt really find anything on that, but it does the same as the rest. 

Btw, the tcp: tag is because named pipes is disabled and I dont need to deal with a named pipes timeout when its not enabled in the first place.

Lastly, I have tried setting a longer timeout and setting a short timeout on the connection and the failover partner with no luck.